# Plotly colorbar legend not showing max or min value

Tags: python, plotly, legend

I have a Plotly chart with a colorbar legend.

I'd like this to go from 0 to 100 with the ticks set every 10.

No matter how I try, the chart always starts the ticks at 10 and ends at 90, removing my top and bottom tick.

How can I ensure that the top and bottom tick are shown?

MWE:

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go


x = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

z = 100*xx*yy

figure = go.Figure()
figure.add_trace(
        go.Contour(
            z=z.flatten(),
            x=xx.flatten(),
            y=yy.flatten(),
            zmin=0,
            zmax=100,
            colorbar_tickvals=np.arange(0, 101, 10),
            colorbar_tickmode='array',
        )
)
figure.update_layout(
    template="simple_white",
)

figure.show()
```

[image: Contour map example]

Comment: Please provide your code, it is very hard to help without a provided code.

Comment: You need what is being answered [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/create-colorbar-from-a-source-label-string-rather-than-integer-python/16576) for you.

Comment: Code for MWE is submitted as an edit

Answer (score 3):

According to the [official website](https://plotly.com/python/contour-plots/), you should add this.

```
contours=dict(
            start=0,
            end=100,
            size=10,
        ),
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

The updated code is,

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go


x = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

z = 100*xx*yy

figure = go.Figure()
figure.add_trace(
        go.Contour(
            z=z.flatten(),
            x=xx.flatten(),
            y=yy.flatten(),
            zmin=0,
            zmax=100,
            colorbar_tickvals=np.arange(0, 101, 10),
            colorbar_tickmode='array',
            contours=dict(
            start=0,
            end=100,
            size=10,
        ),
        )
)
figure.update_layout(
    template="simple_white",
)

figure.show()
```

From my experience, there is no change in the plot with removing `colorbar_tickvals=np.arange(0, 101, 10),colorbar_tickmode='array',`.

Comment: Hi @agcgn! Thanks for your answer. Could you post a picture of the results, for fair comparison with the other answers?

Comment: Also, as you were the earliest to suggest the `contours` argument, I feel like your answer is more deserving than the others that do the same (so far)!

Comment: The downside with this answer is that it a) results in unused colors in the colormap (ie the >100 and <0 colors) and b) results in an extended colorbar, that doesn't neatly terminate at the final values.

Comment: The problem is that giving hard-coded values for the contour levels does not provide an answer to the OP which uses autocontour (default), and has probably in mind to plot contours for _any_ datasets, not only for this MWE.

Comment: By the way, in the example the first level is 10, end is 90. Contours levels represent boundaries between region having data. Adding a boundary at 0 and 100 only leads to unpredictable behavior and does not solve the issue : see the additional region at the bottom left of the plot, which should not exist, it's tiny yes, but what happens with a smaller coordinate space ? And with completely different datasets ? See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

If discrete colors are necessary, I found an alternative workaround to @EricLavault's method of swapping to the `heatmap` style coloring.

This uses the fact that:

- `go.Heatmap` shows start and end ticks
- You can construct custom colorscales
- You can show/hide colorbars

I wrote a little function that you can use to generate a *discrete* colorscale that you can use with an empty `go.Heatmap` to achieve the desired result.

```py
import plotly 
import numpy as np

def discrete_colorscale(n, colorscale="viridis"):
    """Generate a discretised version of a colorscale, with n discrete colors."""
    # Plotly colorscales are lists of float-color pairs, where the floats are
    # numbers in [0, 1] and the colors are Plotly color strings.
    # First, generate the float values. We want n colors, so we need n + 1 values.
    values = np.linspace(0, 1, n + 1)
    # Next, pick n colors from the colorscale.
    colors = plotly.colors.sample_colorscale(
        colorscale, n, low=0, high=1, colortype="rgb"
    )
    # We want the color to be constant for all values between two edges, so set
    # the color of the upper edge to be the same as the color of the lower edge.
    # This trick is described at https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/#constructing-a-discrete-or-discontinuous-color-scale
    lower_edges = [(values[i], colors[i]) for i in range(n)]
    upper_edges = [(values[i + 1], colors[i]) for i in range(n)]
    # This comprehension interleaves the two lists; resulting list is:
    # [lower_edges[0], upper_edges[0], lower_edges[1], upper_edges[1], ...]
    return [x for pair in zip(lower_edges, upper_edges) for x in pair]
```

Using this function would look like this:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go



x = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

z = 100*xx*yy

figure = go.Figure()
figure.add_traces(
    [
        go.Contour(
            z=z.flatten(),
            x=xx.flatten(),
            y=yy.flatten(),
            zmin=0,   # Set zmin and zmax to ensure that the coloring is consistent
            zmax=100, # between the Contour and Heatmap
            ncontours=20, # We want 10 discrete colors, which means 20 contour lines
            colorscale=discrete_colorscale(10), # Same colorscale as the Heatmap
            showscale=False # Hide the Contour colorbar, because it doesn't show end ticks
        ),
        go.Heatmap(
            z=[None], # Dummy data - we only want the Heatmap colorbar
            y=[None],
            x=[None],
            zmin=0,   # Set zmin and zmax to ensure that the coloring is consistent
            zmax=100, # between the Contour and Heatmap
            colorscale=discrete_colorscale(10), # Same colorscale as the Contour
            showscale=True, # Show the heatmap colorbar
        )
    ]
)
# Adding the (empty) Heatmap trace messes up the axis ranges, so we need to set them manually
figure.update_xaxes(range=[0, 1])
figure.update_yaxes(range=[0, 1])

figure.show()
```

Note that **`ncontours` is twice the number of discrete color sections**.

Result:

[image: Contour plot with discrete colors and colorbar start and end ticks]

Comment: Oh I just see this answer, this is a clever approach !

Answer (score 1):

I've a solution for you here:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go


x = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

z = 100*xx*yy

figure = go.Figure()
figure.add_trace(
        go.Contour(
            z=z.flatten(),
            x=xx.flatten(),
            y=yy.flatten(),
            zmin=0,
            zmax=100,
            colorbar = {'tickmode':'linear', 'tick0':0,'dtick':5, 'nticks':10}
        )
)
figure.update_layout(
    template="simple_white",
)

figure.show()
```

This will show your top and bottom ticks for your given code, but **be warned** it only goes from 5 to 95. Unfortunately, I tried tinkering with the given params and this is what it says for the `nticks` param:

```
Specifies the maximum number of ticks for the
particular axis. The actual number of ticks will be
chosen automatically to be less than or equal to
`nticks`. Has an effect only if `tickmode` is set to "auto".
```

Hope this helps!

Edit: here's the resulting plot

[image]

**Edit**:
So after going through the plethora of your comments on this particular question, I've come to realize that you want:

- To be able to handle discrete values
- To be able to show the end values of your specified array

Based on these assumptions here is a full solution to your issue:

1. For discrete values:

```
colorbar = {'ticks':'inside', 'tickvals': [10, 30, 58, 76, 120]},
contours_coloring='heatmap'
```

This will produce discrete values for your plot as such:
[image]

The `ticks` param takes 'inside' or 'outside' you can play with it according to your requirements

2. For having edges the full values displayed in your colorbar:

```
colorbar = {'ticks':'inside', 'tickvals': [0, 10, 22, 25, 30, 58, 76, 77, 89, 100]},
contours_coloring='heatmap'
```

Which produces a graph like this:
[image]

I hope this finally solves your issue

Comment: Could you provide a picture of the resulting graph?

Comment: Added the picture now in an edit

Comment: For more info you can read [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed edits! However I think that your have misunderstood what I meant by 'discrete coloring' - I was talking about blocks of color for which A < z < B, rather than a continuous scale.

Comment: why did you refer to the matplotlib docs?

Answer (score 0):

There would almost certainly be better ways to achieve this, but I think you can try modifying `zmin` and `zmax` parameters. From the docstring:

> ```
>     "zmax
>         Sets the upper bound of the color domain. Value should
>         have the same units as in `z` and if set, `zmin` must
>         be set as well."
> ```

So, the code could be replaced like this:

```
figure.add_trace(
        go.Contour(
            z=z.flatten(),
            x=xx.flatten(),
            y=yy.flatten(),
            zmin=-1,
            zmax=101,
            colorbar_tickvals=np.arange(0, 101, 10),
            colorbar_tickmode='array',
        )
)
```

Comment: Could you provide a picture of the resulting graph?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the (plotly.js) code responsible for drawing the colorbar, I think this is a bug, cf. this [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/6623) I just opened.

Until it is resolved, the best thing you can do imho is to use the "heatmap" [contours coloring](https://plotly.com/python/reference/contour/#contour-contours-coloring) method (not affected by the bug) instead of the default "fill". The contour levels (boundaries) will remain the same, the only difference is :

> If "fill", coloring is done evenly between each contour level. If "heatmap", a heatmap gradient coloring is applied between each contour level.

```py
figure.add_trace(
    go.Contour(
        z=z.flatten(),
        x=xx.flatten(),
        y=yy.flatten(),
        zmin=0,
        zmax=100,
        colorbar_tickvals=np.arange(0, 101, 10),
        colorbar_tickmode='array',
        contours_coloring='heatmap'
    )
)
```

[image: screenshot]

---

The problem with other answers is that they just give hard-coded contour levels, while the OP has probably in mind to plot contours for *any* datasets, not only for this MWE, hence the implicit use of `autocontour` (default).

Also, clearly in the example the first level is 10, end is 90. Contour levels represent boundaries *between* regions with data in it. By setting contour start at 0, not only it affects the colorscale, but it adds a contour between the point (x=0, y=0, z=0) and the neighbor values lower than 10 while they should be in the same region with the same color (and setting `zmin=-1` and `zmax=101` causes the same problem : hard-code, bad result).

See for example the region appearing at the bottom left in @agcgn's screenshot, which should not exist. It's tiny yes, but see what happens with `x = y = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)` :

[image]

The region is colored as "less than 0", whereas z doesn't include any negative value, the output is just as inconsistent as unpredictable.

Comment: Thanks for opening an issue! I agree with your comment about the other answers messing with the colormapping and the range. I'm also not sure they're quite up to 'publication quality' with the colorbar that extends beyond the range of displayed values.

Comment: Obviously, this solution changes the resulting graph significantly; what if the user wanted the discrete coloring of a contour-style plot? You acknowledge that this is a temporary fix, though, which is commendable. I think other temporary fixes might exist that don't compromise the block contour style

Comment: Awarded the bounty for a) submitting an issue to the Plotly Github, b) clear explanation of reasoning, c) acknowledging shortcomings and trying to find a workaround! Thanks!

Comment: Hey nearly at the same time.. I just found a fix, I'm going to make some tests and submit a PR, hopefully it will be accepted and merged soon !

Comment: Oh awesome! Extra points for you then <3

Comment: Makes sense! I hope the fix gets merged

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

z = 100 * xx * yy

figure = go.Figure(
    go.Contour(
        z=z.flatten(),
        x=xx.flatten(),
        y=yy.flatten(),
        zmin=0,
        zmax=100,
        contours=dict(
            start=0,
            end=100,
            size=10,
        ),
    )
)

figure.update_layout(template="simple_white")

figure.show()
```

Here's the output I got:

[image]

Comment: This solution appears to be identical to previously posted solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**: Use *contours* argument, as @agcgn has pointed out.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = 100*xx*yy

figure = go.Figure()
figure.add_trace(
        go.Contour(
            z=z.flatten(),
            x=xx.flatten(),
            y=yy.flatten(),
            # zmin=-100, # zmin zmax not necessary 
            # zmax=110,
            colorbar_tickvals=np.arange(0, 101, 10), # necessary, without it the legend text won't show 100
            # colorbar_tickmode='array', # colorbar_tickmode not necessary
            colorbar_len=1.2, # stretch the legend so it's vertically aligned with the contour lines in the plot
            contours=dict(
                start=0,
                end=100,
                size=10,
            ),
        )
)
figure.update_layout(
    template="simple_white",
    width=400,
    height=400
)

figure.show()
```

[image]

**Solution 2**: Change the min and max value of the matrix z, so that min(z) < 0 and max(z) > 100.

The problem is not a matter of legend, it is what a contour really means.

What you are asking for is not what a contour plot can logically provide neither in plotly nor in other plot libraries, given the current value range (0, 100) of the matrix z.

> [A contour line ... is a curve along which the function has a constant value, so that the curve joins points of equal value.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line)

In your matrix z of size 50 by 50, there is only a single point z[49,49] that the value is 100. And although there are many points' values are 0, they only exist on the top most and left most border of the matrix. So technically there is no curve to be drawn "inside" the matrix to connect points of value 0 or 100.

[image]

The only way to show 0 and 100 on the legend without directly specifying the contour lines is to modify the min max value of the matrix z, so that the min(z) < 0 and max(z) > 100. Only then you can draw a curve between points of <0 and of >0 and another curve between points of >100 and of <100 in the contour.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = 100*xx*yy

z[49,49] = 100.1; z[0,0] = -0.1

figure = go.Figure()
figure.add_trace(
        go.Contour(
            z=z.flatten(),
            x=xx.flatten(),
            y=yy.flatten(),
            # zmin=-100, # no need to specify zmin and zmax
            # zmax=110,
            colorbar_tickvals=np.arange(0, 101, 10),
            colorbar_tickmode='array',
            colorbar_len=1.2 # to stretch the legend so it keeps vertically aligned with the contours in the plot
        )
)
figure.update_layout(
    template="simple_white",
    width=400,
    height=400
)

figure.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This appears to be the same solution as @agcgn's answer. The only differences are the comments to the code, which would probably be better suited as a comment on agcgn's post, and the colorbar stretching (which isn't asked for in original question, is a nice touch in this specific case, but probably isn't usefully transferable)

Comment: However, I feel like your original (unedited) answer might actually have contributed more to the discussion - why did you remove it?

Comment: yes I upvoted @agcgn's answer. but there's no image showing the actual plot result, so I feel the need to provide a more comprehensive answer. I'm glad that you found my previous solution useful, I will edit and make it option 2

Comment: I think with discrete 'block colour' contour plots, what you're actually showing is regions for which A < z < B; if it was just a contour *line* plot, then you are correct that there is no curve to be drawn.

Answer (score -1):

```
trace = go.Heatmap( colorscale=COLORSCALE,
                    colorbar = dict(
                        tickvals = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
                        tickmode = 'array',
                    )
                    ...
        )
```

would be one way, in Python; practically the same in JS

But as @Levent pointed out, we can't tell you what ***you*** need without code.

Comment: This doesn't work - see pending edit with MWE

Comment: Well, all I can say is ... it worked 6 years ago. I haven't used plotly pretty much since then but the application I used it with, where I used that code, still works afaik

Comment: @theo-brown Have you tried using the exact `colorbar = dict(…)` syntax I used? Particularly, `numpy.arange` doesn't exactly return an array. I'm just grasping at straws, because if it couldn't use an `arange` I'd hope it would have objected, but  your zmin/zmax values would mean that the bar ticks would have those values if you hadn't specified the tickvals, anyway.

Comment: Oh, sorry, `numpy.arange` _does_ return an array, I misread the numpy doc. But still, if you leave out the colorbar options I'd expect you to have what you see.

Comment: What do you mean leave out the colorbar options? Plotly magic underscore notation means that my colorbar code is the same as yours (see https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/#figures-as-graph-objects for magic underscore description)

Comment: @theo-brown i understand it _should_ work that way, but when we have a working system, and a different non-working system, it seems best to duplicate the working system first. I _said_ I was grasping at straws By "leave out the colorbar options", i mean exactly that -- if you have none, i expect you to see exactly the same thing

Comment: Ah I believe I've found part of the issue - your answer is using Heatmap, my MWE is using Contour. Heatmap has ticks that start/end at the end of the colorbar, whereas contour doesn't.

Comment: @theo-brown That sucks. I'm afraid I can't help you then.

Comment: Fair enough - sorry for the downvote, it feels unfair given the OP didn't provide a MWE. I would un-downvote if I could!

Comment: Hey, @theo-brown I don't worry about downvotes. Back when my contributions to this site were much higher, the upvotes far exceeded them, now they just don't matter. A downvote just means "doesn't work for me", and obviously while I stand by my solution for _my_ case, it's not the same for yours.